# Manually adjustable shape in matlab

Tags: image-segmentation

I need to manually segment images in matlab. I would love to use "impoly" but I mostly need to segment rounded objects.

I found exactly what I need in video of Ali Pashaei on Youtube, in "FlowImageProcessing toolbox v2.0" he uses 5 points to create ellipse and then he can adjust it.

You can see it in this video as SegmentImage.m function. https://youtu.be/R7XtbXAa8LI?t=124

Does anyone know what should I use for achieving similar result? Or does anyone know where can I find work of Mr. Pashaei?

I have found "PulsatileFlow_toolkit" but it does not contain function I need.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`imellipse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imellipse.html)? It is similar to `impoly`bit lets you work with dragable
ellipse instead of an arbitrary polygon.